# vmbox install centOS case error"No DEfault or ui configuration directive found boot"

Tags: php, linux, centos

i'm use vmbox install centOS,the program option is right, but is run error it case"No DEfault or ui configuration directive found boot",can i need another option or how do it

Answer (score -2, accepted):

the reason was find: the centOS my donwload is not full version. the next download was install success